# Issue with font replacement in captions when using math mode

Tags: fonts, captions

I'm getting annoying font replacement warnings of the kind:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <10.5> not available

and

> LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences (Font) up to 0.45pt have occurred.

These occur when I add commands that alter the font in the caption of an image. For example,

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Fig.pdf}
\caption{Dummy$^2$} 
\end{figure}
```

leads to the aforementioned warnings being printed, whereas

```
\caption{Dummy2}
```

does not. While these substitutions are not errors but merely warnings, I would like to be rid of them once and for all. Can someone suggest a method or a reason for addressing them?

Comment: Try `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before `\documentclass`.